# Is Mac OS X required to submit an app to the iOS App Store?

Tags: windows, ios-appstore

We are about to develop an application using [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/), a cross platform mobile development tool, but they offer a [service](https://build.phonegap.com/) where they will build your applications and send you the compiled source code.

Can I submit the compiled source code to the App Store on a Windows-based PC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the compiled code must be submitted via a Mac. One "workaround" is to install OS X into a virtual machine on Windows, but that violates the OS X user agreement. So yes, you'll need a Mac.

Comment: Theoretically, could Phonegap also offer the service of submitting for you?

Comment: There's a great answer on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870020/distributing-a-third-party-developed-application-via-app-store/6870341#6870341). In short, not really. It may work for individual developers, but not with one company (Phonegap) submitting multiple apps from different companies.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure we HAD to buy some macbooks. I didn't want to lie to upper management. I can't wait to get them!

Comment: HA! Nice. Enjoy the new shiny.